# Application not installing over USB after adding service process name?

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-debugging

I have a foreground service and in the manifest I have added a process name for the service. After that the application is not getting installed on the device. FYI My device is Poco F1 Android Q, MiUi 11

I've tried the below things as well,

- Enabled Install Via USB
- Enabled USB Debugging
- Disabled Verify Apps over USB
- Disabled Verify bytecode of debuggable apps
- Disabled security scanner of Mi

Also, I'm using `Android Studio 4.1 Beta`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is it occuring only for this application or all applications?

Comment: This one alone, if I remove the service process name it will start working again @AgentP